# Magento 1.9 api/rest 404 error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, virtualhost

Recently I have moved a magento 1.9 but the api/rest url is 404ing.

The site is running on php 7.0 on a virtual host.

I have added

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this isn't working :/

I have also cheched the .htaccess file for

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

The api/rest works fine on my local version but just not on the live server.

Any help with this would be a god send :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

In the .conf file I needed to remove `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento>
      AllowOverride All
      # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you pls tell me the file location?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `Options -MultiViews` instead of `Options FollowSymlinks`.